# Kendo UI prompt only 1 button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Greeting All,

Im using KENDO UI PROMPT.

1. I want to rename "**OK**" to "**UNLOCK**"
2. I want to remove "**Cancel**" button, so only 1 button available on this prompt. Its possible to do? If not is there any option on my situation like this?

```js
$("#promptBtn").on("click", function () {
  window.myprompt("Please enter password!").then(function (data) {
    window.location.pathname = "unlock.php";
  })
});


function myprompt(content, defaultValue){
  return $("<div></div>").kendoPrompt({
    title: "Lock Session",
    content: content
  }).data("kendoPrompt").open().result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="promptBtn" class="k-button">myprompt</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could create your own dialog (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog) with the input element in the body and only one button.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it cannot do that, so I need to use kendoWindow for that!

```js
var lockScreen = $("#lockScreen");
lockScreen.kendoWindow({
  visible: false,
  width: "200px",
  height: "130px",
  actions: [],
  modal: true,
  title: "LOCKED!"
});
$("#menuLock").click(function() {
    lockScreen.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
});
```

```css
 *{font-size:11px; font-family:Arial;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/constrain-movement">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  


<button id="menuLock" >KENDO WINDOW</button>

  
<div id="lockScreen">
  <form action="#" method="POST">
  <p>Please enter your password!</p>
  <input id="" type="password" class="k-textbox" name="password" style="width: 180px;" />
  <button class="k-button k-primary" style="width:100%; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; padding: 15px 25px;">Unlock</button> 
 <span id="notification" style="display:none;" ></span>
  </form>
</div> 
  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also use KendoDialog for this.